# Need to make an exact copy of HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-cloning

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (Desktop edition). I made an image of a whole disk by using Clonezilla. I've got my servers running on Ubuntu and I want to have a duplicate hard drive in case the old drive fails.

I'll attach two pictures of both drives with all the info about them. They seem to be exactly the same.

Is it possible to just put a new disk and run Clonezilla in order to produce the duplicate drive? And what's more important: would that new drive work exactly the same and would I need to change anything in Ubuntu?

My logic tells me that if it's gonna be the exact copy then I'm all set to use it in case the previous drive fails.

This is my old drive with Ubuntu on it
[image: This is my old drive with Ubuntu on it]

This is my new and blank HD
[image: This is my new and blank HD]

Comment: > " would that new drive work exactly the same" I would expect so, mostly. But not entirely.  The serial number may be different.  I recall the original Xbox supported "locking", using a feature called "ATA Security".  Now, these minor differences are unlikely to cause Ubuntu to fail to boot up, but just goes to show that duplicating the partition structure, partitions, and even a bit-for-bit/forensic image may not be a 100% perfect duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just give it a try? You're going to have to perform an actual test of the cloned drive anyway. After all the drive may be faulty or people on the Internet may be wrong.

> Is it possible to just put a new disk and run Clonezilla in order to produce the duplicate drive?

Yes, mostly. Clonezilla images by default don't contain data that isn't referenced in the filesystem, like remnants of deleted files. So there may be differences, but nothing that would affect operation of the system. Partition structure and files will be exactly identical.

> would that new drive work exactly the same

Yes.

> would I need to change anything in Ubuntu?

No. It won't notice a difference.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... I'll give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Clonezilla, but you can directly copy partitions (using `cp` or `dd`, or possibly even Clonezilla images, if Clonezilla doesn't include extra information in them), provided that the source and destination partition have the same size (or the destination partition is larger, but then you'll waste space).

Which means the simplest way to duplicate an existing hard drive is to look at the partitions, manually create similar partitions on the destination hard drive, attach both to a computer and copy them over.

No Clonezilla needed.

Comment: By default Clonezilla produces gzipped partclone image which can't be written directly to disk, it must be uncompressed and piped to partclone to restore. The advantage of partclone is that only data referenced in filesystem is imaged, without free space. Clonezilla isn't necessary, but it's convenient and much more efficient: it will recreate original partition layout for you and restore only relevant data.

Comment: Clonezilla seems to be much more convenient and fast. But I do have also Gzipped tarballs of everything. But then I would have to adjust certain things inside OS and that's something I don't wanna mess with. Hopefully with Clonezilla I won't have to go through that....